# Is it technically possible to upgrade TFS 2010 to TFS 2013 Express?

Tags: windows, team-foundation-server, upgrade

Is there a supported upgrade path from Team Foundation Server 2010 Professional to Team Foundation Server 2013 Express?  Is this possible on technical level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in what any reasonable person would call an upgrade.

[The published "upgrade path" for Team Foundation Server 2010 to 2013 on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620933.aspx) is to uninstall TFS 2010, and then install TFS 2013.  To actually upgrade without uninstalling, you have to be running TFS 2012.

[According to this MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wadep/archive/2012/10/10/upgrading-tfs-2010-to-2012.aspx), there's an upgrade path for TFS 2010 to TFS 2012, which can preserve settings, [but it also involves uninstalling TFS 2010 as part of the process](http://nakedalm.com/upgrading-tfs-2010-to-tfs-2012-with-vss-migration-and-process-template-consolidation/).  Looks like quite a pain to me, but the good news is you should be able to use that upgrade guide to capture whatever settings or configurations you have now, so that you can replicate them on your new TFS 2013 install, if that's your concern.

Comment: Just as addendum, I've had to do this a few years back and [tfs 2008 can be downgraded](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/37761425-053e-4384-8651-bed149d86cc4/team-foundation-server-downgrade?forum=tfssetup). But I can't find any documentation that says the edition can be downgraded while upgrading versions, it might complicate matters, as the downgrade also writes updates to the database.